# GCP - Gke standalone, how to masquerade 10.0.0/8 cidr

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We are using GKE in kubernatees, and we are using **10.0.0.0/8** cidr range for all our private ips which is shared with our on-prem and AWS network as well.

out pods and service ip from K8 cluster is from non rfs **240.0.120.0/24** cidr range.  Now this is the issue, when we try to connect any GCP or AWS resource it's not able to connect and needs masquerading.

However, masquerading document says it's wont' masquerade if destination IP is from cidr **10.0.0.0/8**

**links I am referring too **

- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/ip-masq-agent#agent-flags
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ip-masquerade-agent
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ip-masquerade-agent#default-non-masq-dests

I am confuse what to do, there is not section in ConfigMap to add **masqueradeCIDRs**, it only has a section to add **nonMasqueradeCIDRs**

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigMao for ip-masq lists the CIDRs for which you do not want to masquerade.  If you don't specify a ConfigMap, then the default includes `10.0.0.0/8` in the non-masquerade list.

You'll need to follow the docs on [creating the ConfigMap](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#creating_the_ip-masq-agent_configmap) and you'll need to minimally add the ranges you use for your pods/services (the 240.) to the non-masquerade list.  You want to make sure the `10.0.0.0/8` is NOT in the ConfigMap.

Comment: I created the config map and deployed it. however, it's still not working. I restarted the demon set as well, but still no help. do I have to re-deploy the demon-set?

Answer (score 1):

You can try enabling IP masquerade. First you identify the network where your GKE cluster is running. Then identify the subnet associated with your GKE cluster within that network. Enable IP masquerading on the subnet using the command below. Make sure to replace [SUBNET_NAME] with the name of your GKE cluster's subnet.